# How can I add the application settings to my installer in a WPF project?

Tags: c#, wpf, application-settings, settings.settings

I do have a C# (WPF)-Application whith several application settings, generated in the Visual Studio 2010. With the "Advanced Installer" I would like to create an installer-setup in order to install my application to any PC.

Therefore I add to the installer the *application.exe* file from my **release folder**. After installation on a different PC I can not find the *application settings* which were generated in VS before. My question is now, which file(s) I need to add to my installer-package in order to see the application settings after installation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Application Scope Settings* are persisted in the applications **config file**. It is located in the applications output directory and called `[ApplicationName].exe.config`. This is probably the one you want.

*User scope settings* are persisted in the file User.config in the users settings folder:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\[UserName]\Local Settings\Application Data\[ApplicationName]
```

Vista and Windows 7, 8:

```
C:\Users\[UserName]\Local Settings\Application Data\[ApplicationName]
```

If you need to add the user config file to the installer package, make sure to use the correct directory in advanced installer. A helpful list is [here](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/folder-paths.html). Use `Local application data`, create a subfolder with your app name there and add `user.config` to this folder:

[image]

You can find more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).